# Showing old cluster ips when i run nodetool status for new cluster

Tags: cassandra

I already have a cassandra cluster of 4 nodes (version 1.2.5). I made an image of one of the cassandra instance in the existing cluster and created new cluster with 2 nodes. When i started new instances and checked nodetool status it is showing the old cluster ips also. Checked the cassandra.yaml file. Seeds are set for new nodes only. What else needs to be changed?

Answer (score 1):

I think the cluster metainfo is stored in the `system` keyspace--check the `peers` table.

Answer (score 0):

@Alex Popescu , Thanks that worked for me.

1)SELECT * FROM system.peers; - gave me the entries for the hosts .

2)REMOVED the entry for unwanted node.

3)Ran nodetool flush system.

4)Restarted cassandra on all nodes of the cluster.